# if/else with foreach and if statement inside - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I keep getting syntax errors on this piece of code.

```
<?php 

$day = get_field_object('day_of_the_week');
$value = $day['value'];
$choices = $day['choices'];

    if( $value ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $value as $v ): ?>
                <li>
                    <?php if( $v != $page_title ) { ?>
                        <a class="btn" href="/venture-centre/activities-2/<?php echo $choices[ $v ]; ?>#<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>">
                            <?php echo $choices[ $v ]; ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <?php } else { ?>
                    <p>This activity is only available on <?php echo $page_title ?>.</p>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i think this mixing of PHP and HTML code is neither beautiful nor you can work on such pages some months later effectively. Try to seperate your HTML and PHP code as good as you can

Comment: I absolutely agree, it was the first part of the code that I used from somewhere and as a previous iteration of the above code was working fine I didn't think it was a big issue - just wanted to get something working then refine the code

Comment: @messerbill - I've just realised I miss-understood your original message... So what you're saying is that all of the code above should be within one piece of PHP, outputting HTML where required?

Comment: yes, its better to build clean php scripts and make them loading HTML template files or just return them (HTML codes) as a return value of a php function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, I've made the suggested changes and realise that I needed an `elseif` in place of the `else` to complete what I was trying to achieve:

```
<?php 

$day = get_field_object('day_of_the_week');
$value = $day['value'];
$choices = $day['choices'];

if( count($value) > 1 ) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $value as $v ) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php if( $v != $page_title ) { ?>
                    <a class="btn" href="/venture-centre/activities-2/<?php echo $choices[ $v ]; ?>#<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>">
                        <?php echo $choices[ $v ]; ?>
                    </a>
            </li>
        <?php } } } elseif( count($value) == 1 ) { ?>
                        <p>This activity is only available on <?php echo $page_title; ?>.</p>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing standard and alternative syntax, which is not permitted:

```
if( $value ): ?>   // start alternative syntax block
    <?php } else { ?>  // where did this get opened?
```

Comment: Yes, have changed this and made further changes to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing curly brace without an opening one.

See `<?php } ?>` after the `</a>`

You have to remove this line or add `<?php { ?>` after the for each